# PHP Login Script Not working in IE on a specific computer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, authentication

I have a perplexing problem. I am building a login system for a website, and on one user's computer only in IE 9, the sign in script fails. I have checked using Fiddler that the proper POST data is being sent. I would work with that computer more, but I don't have that oppurtunity.

I know the correct login details are being sent; the correct errors are sent out by the PHP script when incorrect login details are sent, and the login fails for all accounts. The sign in system uses PHP sessions. I am completely baffled by this, and have never seen anything like it.

The site located at [gatewaymma.com](http://www.gatewaymma.com/) I have setup a test account that does not have any special access:

username: testAcc

pwd: test22

**Again this only occurs in IE 9, no other browser, and only on the one machine (win 7), so I have not been able replicate it, and as far as I can tell, the correct $_POST data is recieved.**

If someone could replicate this or give a possible area that they have seen that may be causing this it would be much appreciated.

I had thought that cookie security might be causing the problem, but after adding a check for cookies, no errors were produced.

Here is a portion of the login script:

```
            if(/* the password was correct, there is def no problem here*/){
                
                session_regenerate_id(true);
                
                $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                /*set other session vars*/
                
                
                DB::query("UPDATE fa_logged_ips SET tries = 0, next_try = 0 WHERE ip = %s LIMIT 1", $_SESSION['ip']);
                
                DB::query("UPDATE fa_users SET last_login = $_SESSION[last_activity] WHERE ID = %s LIMIT 1", $_SESSION['uid']);
            }
        }
        //If the login was not successful (this error message is not fired, so I don't believe the session is being lost somewhere after this point
        if($_SESSION['logged'] !== TRUE){
            $fArray['loginErr'] = "The username and password combination you entered is not valid.";
            check_ip();
        }
```

Notice that the last section of the script checks that the user is logged in, meaning that the session was successfully created, but that it is somehow being lost when the user is redirected to the home page.

EDIT: One more thing, this login system is derived from one that I launched on another section of the site (on a subdomain) that works fine on the same computer, and has so for the last 5 months.

EDIT:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){

formatSession();
setcookie('cookieTest', '1', time()+3600*24*30); //set a cookie that will be checked for later
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  //Get the user's ip address

//Check if the IP is logged in the system
$logged_ip = DB::queryFirstRow("SELECT * FROM fa_logged_ips WHERE ip = %s", $ip);

//if so
if(!empty($logged_ip)){
    
    //if ip has too many failed logins
    if ($logged_ip["tries"] < $login_attempt_limit) {   
        $_SESSION['next_try'] = $logged_ip["next_try"]; //store when their lockout ends
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['next_try'] = 0; //otherwise they may try to log in at their discretion
    }
    
    $_SESSION['tries'] = intval($logged_ip["tries"]); //store how many login tries the ip has
}               
}

The session format funciton

 function formatSession(){
global $sysEnable;

$_SESSION['logged'] = false;        //The user is not logged in
$_SESSION['sysEnable'] = $sysEnable;//Store wether or not the system is accessible
}
```

**EDIT**

I strongly feel this is related to some kind of security setting in IE, because I have only seen it occur on the one computer, and have not been able to replicate it on any other machine. In addition I was able to produce a similar effect by turning up the cookie security, but as stated before, the cookie check was successful on the computer

**EDIT 9/1**

I think that IE may be failing to maintain the session; IE isn't saving the session id. Again I haven't been able replicate this behavior, so can't be 100% positive until I can work with that computer.

Comment: Can you provide more context in your code.  Particularly, can we see where locatoins where $_SESSION['logged'] might possibly be set?

Comment: I have just tested on IE9 Windows 7 64bit and it logged me in fine and i could navigate the site staying logged in. No errors on my console. - sorry that doesnt help much but thought it might help deduce if it is an issue with the computer rather than your website.

Comment: Again, if you read the question, I have not been able to replicate this on my own computer. I know it will work on most computers without any problems.

Comment: You seem to have 1 `}` closing curly too many, you're DB object is **static** which seems to me to be a bad idea, but that's none of my business. Have you checked to see if a session cookie is being set (yes, sessions do use cookies), if not: accept cookies or pass your session id via post

Comment: How are you testing to see if the form is submitted? A common unknown in IE is that it does not POST the submit button, if you are relying on that to catch the event.

Comment: Please read the question, I said I checked with fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that the post request was sent to the server.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The extra bracket comes from some validation that checks for the post data. I have checked for cookies; the updated code shows where the cookie is set. On the login page it throws an error if the cookie is missing (I have tested this by turning up the cookie security settings).

Comment: Please, fix this line `"SELECT * FROM fa_logged_ips WHERE ip = '$ip'"`, you're using raw, unprocessed data that is sent via the network -- never trust a network! your app is vulnerable if this is how you build queries, think about using a PDO object. And if you do want to keep at building queries this way, replace things like `WHERE ip = '$_SESSION[ip]' LIMIT 1"` with `WHERE ip = '{$_SESSION['ip']}' LIMIT 1"` so there can be no confusion as to what is part of the variable. your code now could set the query to `WHERE ip = 'Array[ip]' LIMIT 1"`, only replacing `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Greg Rozmarynowycz: If you switch to IE compatibility mode (which is IE7) - your page falls apart. I personally don't think that you should care about this and start fixing but you must tell a user by giving a notice that your site doesn't support IE7 and below. You can make a function to check it by doing something like: if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8){ return true;} If it returns true than show user a global warning to update their old browser..

Comment: @Greg Rozmarynowycz: I strongly recommend to use mysql_real_escape_string to all data that you sent to database to prevent SQL injection!! Use something like this everywhere "SELECT * FROM fa_logged_ips WHERE ip = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($ip) . "'

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev To my dismay, I am not in charge of the layout of the page - I did not do the initial setup of the site, most of what I'm doing is administrative add-ons. I would like to fix the many layout issues the site has, but that's another persons responsibility.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev The query class handles processing the query, do not worry about that. And `mysql_real_escape_string` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is depracated and insecure, if I did not have my query class, I would use (and have used) the `mysqli` functions.

Comment: Updated my answer, might be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I have stumbled upon this recently! I couldn't believe my eyes that it was happening - because the post data was passed correctly! I have built precise login script and only in IE I had kind of the same problem!

What I had was that when you hit enter after login and password is entered in the fields, and when in all other browsers login happened just fine, in IE I just had the page kind of refreshed. BUT if I clicked signin button under the password field than everything went just fine!

There was no logical explanation to that and now I must say it's just IE unnoticed bug!

What I did is detected the users browser and if it's IE I canceled enter key and forced user to click signin button.

Here is my code to solve this crazy problem:

```
function browserIE(){
 if($.browser.msie){ 
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13' && browserIE()){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
});
```

That was the only way to force IE user to click singin button to make proper signin because as I said before hitting enter being on fields just failed in my case too!

### Edited:

### Another Solution 1

The other solution could be but it didn't work in my case is to add additional hidden input field:

```
<!-- Fix for Internet Explorer bug (One text input and submit, disables submit on pressing "Enter") -->
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="hiddenText"/>
  </div>
```

### Another Solution 2

It appears that Internet Explorer scans the page at load time and figures out which submit buttons are visible, then attaches the enter-to-submit functionality to those forms.

To fix this scenario, you can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').keydown(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        return false;
     }
   });
});
```

The return false is rather important in Internet Explorer, because it prevents that beep that you might hear if you hit return. The beep is saying "you can't hit enter here!", but return false cancels the key press and therefore the browser won't warn.

Read more about this and what people comment: [Submit a Form in IE with Enter](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter)

Also Recommend reading: [Button versus Input[type="submit"] in Internet Explorer and beyond](http://ajaxian.com/archives/button-versus-inputtypesubmit-in-ie-and-beyond)

Comment: Although this is an issue (that I still have to fix), this is not the issue; When this first occurred I had thought something like this was the issue. But the page does not merely refresh, it does login because it redirects to the homepage, something the script only does when it logs in.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant but did you solve this 'not the issue'?

Comment: Its the not the same as the issue in the question